# Caption of a figure exceeds the page using IEEE Access Template

Tags: captions, templates, ieeeaccess

I create a long caption for my figure but it says `Overfull \hbox` warning and the caption exceeds the page in PDF output. I can do like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_does_the_long_caption_of_a_figure_exceed_the_page_margins_in_IEEE_access_template) by changing:
`\ifdim \xfigwd >\columnwidth%` to `\ifdim \xfigwd >\linewidth%` in `cls` file line 227 (donwload IEEE Access template [here](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/)) but i dont want to change the `cls` file. A code:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){fig1.png}
{Magnetization as a function of applied field.
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption.\label{fig1}}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

those lines will output this:
[image: output]

Any suggestion?

EDIT:
Because my picture is large, I need one full wide column to place it (not in the left or right column).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code segment to complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which we can test as it is. Also pleas not use links, they can become death after while.

Comment: @Zarko queastion is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, if the following will work for you:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\Figure[t!]()[width=0.8\linewidth]{fig1.png} % <--- define width of figure
{Magnetization as a function of applied field.
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption.\label{fig1}}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

If I understood your comment correctly, than the size of your image is to large that can be fit into one column. For such images is defined `figure*` environment. Using them, for captions you need to load the `caption` package. Note, figure will appear at top of the next page from where image is inserted in text:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}   % <--- new
\usepackage[font={sf,small,stretch=0.84},
            labelfont={bf,color=accessblue}
            ]{caption}  % <--- new

\usepackage{lipsum}     % for dummy text filler

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}[ht]     % <--- changed
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{fig1.png}
\caption{Magnetization as a function of applied field.
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption.}
\label{fig1}
    \end{figure*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\EOD

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forget to tell that my picture is quite large that takes 2 columns. I guess your figure is placed on the left column. I need to place my pic on top of page and in full wide. Sorry for this late info.

Comment: @donto, please edit your question and add this information there, that will be visible to all.

Comment: Exactly what I want!. But I wonder if I put my picture without using predefined tag (`\Figure`) will violate the rules of IEEE Access template?

Comment: @donto, about rules of `ieeeacces` you need to ask them. As far as I remember, they retype received article, so I wouldn't worry about this.BTW, caption settings mimic `\Figure` settings.